# how to handle chat history response in xmpp I have already send stanza in android

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, stanza

In my Application, i want to get the chat history from the `XMPP SMACK`,For it i am sending the  `IQPacket stanza` please check below

```
  public void getChatHistory() throws Exception{

        if (connection.isAuthenticated()){

            ChatHistoryIq iq = new ChatHistoryIq("query");
            iq.setType(IQ.Type.set);
            iq.setStanzaId(loginUser);


            System.out.println("************************************** Iq is : "+iq);

                /*New code*/

            connection.sendIqWithResponseCallback(iq, new PacketListener() {
                @Override
               public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws NotConnectedException {
                    CharSequence mCharSequence = (CharSequence) packet.toXML();
                    System.out.println("((((((((((((((((( : " + mCharSequence);
                    String xml=String.valueOf(mCharSequence);
                    loadRSSFromURL(xml);
               }
            });

//The listener for receiving all the packets from the peer device
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {
                @Override
                public void processPacket(Stanza packet) throws NotConnectedException {

                    Log.i("Send IQ with Response", "****** message From : " + packet.getFrom());
                    Log.i("Send IQ with Response", "****** message To : " + packet.getTo());
                    Log.i("XML is *****************************: ", String.valueOf(packet.toXML()));
                }
            }, new PacketFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(Stanza packet) {

                    Log.e("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ CHAT HISTORY Packet Filter From : ", packet.getFrom());
                    Log.e("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ CHAT HISTORY Packet Filter To : ", packet.getTo());
                    Log.i("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ CHAT HISTORY Packet Filter XML: ", packet.toString());

                    String xml=String.valueOf(packet.toXML());
                    loadRSSFromURL(xml);

                    return true;
                }
            });
            connection.sendPacket(iq);
//           
        } else{
            Toast.makeText(context,"User Not Authenticate",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

I am *getting the* ***history*** from the above code but the problem is that , *we are not able to **handle** the chat history* , we are getting it only on our `LOGCAT` but not able to handle it.Means we want some `callback methods` to handle the chat history of `XMPP`. So please help to handle the chat history of XMPP..
Please check the screen shot  of getting the XMPP response [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTbxq.png)